# Ubuntu 18, touchpad click randomly

Tags: touchpad, thinkpad

Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Carbon (G4) 
After last updates my touchpad use left click randomly when i typing. When i disabled 'Tap to click' all work correctly, someone met with that problem?

Comment: Is your hand hovering over the touchpad when you type? it sounds like you are inadvertently touching the mousepad with the palms of your hand while typing

Comment: Please, show the output of `xinput list-props "$(xinput list --name-only | grep -i touchpad)"`.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your palm is touching the mousepad when you type. I'm not sure if this works in ubuntu or not, but you could try `syndaemon -i 0.5 -t -K -R`

`syndaemon # a program that monitors keyboard activity`

`-i # how many seconds to wait after last keyboard click`

`-t # only disable tapping and scrolling`

`-K # ignore modifier keys and modifier+key combos`

`-R #use XRecord extension for detecting keyboard activity ...`

Comment: I don't think it will help because of two reasons: 1) Ubuntu 18.04 is uising `libinput` and `syndaemon won't work; 2) I don't think the problem is with palm touching.

Comment: To me, it looks like a problem with palm touching, especially if the issue goes away disabling tap to click. At OP: check first in Gnome Tweaks on the "Keyboard & Mouse" tab whether "Disable while typing" is (still?) checked.

Comment: I also agree that it sounds like palm touching (guess I should agree haha) since everything works accordingly when tap to click is disabled. At any rate, I'm sure `libinput` must have a similar command?